# Where is the getName method in the View in Gluon 5.0

Tags: java, gluon

```
viewProperty().addListener((obs, oldView, newView) -> {
    switch(newView.getName()) {
        case HOME_VIEW:
            Swatch.INDIGO.assignTo(newView.getScene());
            break;
        case OTHER_VIEW:
            Swatch.GREEN.assignTo(newView.getScene());
            break;
        default:
            Swatch.getDefault().assignTo(newView.getScene());
    }
});
```

This code shows an error on the `getName` method of the View.

**Question:**

How are we supposed to proceed with Gluon 5.0? No more such method

[Link to Java doc of View on Gluon 5.0](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.1/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/mvc/View.html)

Answer (score 0):

`getName()` method has been removed in Gluon Mobile 5.0.0. For a complete list of changes, you can refer to the [migration guide](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.1/#_migration_guide_to_gluon_mobile_5).

You can use [`setOnShowing()`](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.1/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/mvc/View.html#setOnShowing-javafx.event.EventHandler-) on each of these views to take care of the Swatch switch. This can be done in the constructor of each of these views or while adding them to the view factory.

```
public PrimaryView() {
    ...
    setOnShowing(e -> Swatch.INDIGO.assignTo(getScene()));
}

public SecondaryView() {
    ...
    setOnShowing(e -> Swatch.GREEN.assignTo(getScene()));
}
```